# phpMyAdmin not found on Windows

Tags: localhost

I installed WAMP server 2.2 on Windows 7 x64. I clicked on its system tray icon and put the server online. Then I select PhpMyAdmin and I get a 404 page.

Localhost successfully gives me the Apache 2 test page. There's no way I'm able to fix this. The PHP error log and the Apache error logs have no errors.

Note: I've tried all combinations of the url such as `localhost/phpmyadmin/` and `localhost/phpmyadmin` and `localhost/phpmyadmin/?`

Comment: And you are certain that phpMyAdmin is served on port 80?

Comment: I didnt change anything. All I did was install and run. How can i find the port its running on?

Comment: Isn't there a shortcut to phpMyAdmin if you click on the wampserver icon in the system tray?

Comment: ok it seems I had to uninstall my previous installation of mysql server and then re-install wamp. The server is fixed now but Im getting access denied at phpMyAdmin for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well first I had to un-install my previous installation of the MySQL server. This fixed the wamp server which now ran perfectly.
A different issue also cropped up later (not related directly to question). I was getting access denied on the phpMyAdmin page. This I could fix by changing `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = false;` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = true;`
The above lines are in `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries` and search for `config.default.php`

Answer (score 2):

### First

**Make sure that nothing else is using port 80.** Check `netstat -abn` to see what is listening on that port.

One of the biggest culprits is Skype. Look under options >> advanced >> connection and see if "use port 80" is checked. Uncheck if so. Then restart Skype. Might have to restart WAMP too.

Next would be any anti-virus / anti-spam / anti-functionality software. Temporarily disable it to test. If everything works, re-enable it and figure out what portion of the software is blocking the connection.

Check to see if IIS is installed and uninstall it.

### Second

**Check your directory structure.** Open up your web root and make sure that a phpmyadmin folder exists, and also exactly what case its typed in.

Comment: I had to un-install my previous installation of MySQL server and then re-install wamp to make it work. Now the wamp server works fine but Im getting an access denied at phpMyAdmin. I thinks thats a totally different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem and i've come across an easier solution:

left click on the wamp tray icon
apache>
apache modules>
check the 'rewrite module'

bingo!